# ith term of$~\left\{a\right\}=\left\{1,1,3,1,3,5,1,3,5,7,1,3,5,7,9,1,\cdot\cdot\cdot\right\}~$such that$~a_{i}=17~$for j times appearnce

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

$$\left\{a\right\}=\left\{1,1,3,1,3,5,1,3,5,7,1,3,5,7,9,1,\cdot\cdot\cdot\right\}\tag{1}$$

I want to know the value of$~n~$such that following is satisfied.

$$a_{n}=17~~\leftarrow~~\text{this 17 appeared}~m~\text{times inclusive}~~~~\left(m\in\mathbb{N}\right)\tag{2}$$

The official answer states the following.

As we hold$~2i-1=17~$,

$~i=9~$is obtained.

Hence we can say that the first appearnce of 17 in the sequence occurs at 9th term of 9th group.

(My comment). Here the ith group is defined as consecutive subsequences of odd numbers.

E. g,

$$1~\rightarrow~\text{1st group}\tag{3}$$

$$1,3~\rightarrow~\text{2nd group}\tag{4}$$

$$1,3,5~\rightarrow~\text{3rd group}\tag{5}$$

$$1,3,5,7~\rightarrow~\text{4th group}\tag{6}$$

$$1,3,5,7,9~\rightarrow~\text{5th group}\tag{7}$$

$$1,3,5,7,9,11~\rightarrow~\text{6th group}\tag{8}$$

$$1,3,5,7,9,11,13~\rightarrow~\text{7th group}\tag{9}$$

$$1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15~\rightarrow~\text{8th group}\tag{10}$$

$$\underbrace{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17}_\text{9 terms}~\rightarrow~\text{9th group}\tag{11}$$

$$\underbrace{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19}_{\text{10 terms}}~\rightarrow~\text{10th group}\tag{12}$$

> Hence we can say that the first appearnce of 17 in the sequence occurs at 9th term of 9th group.

I can't get the meaning of this.

Can anyone give me hint(s)?

Comment: I think I resolved it in my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we suppose$~i\in\mathbb{N}~$,

$~2i-1~$of coursely takes an odd number and this means that,

$$\text{ith term}=2i-1\tag{1}$$

$$\therefore~~i=9~~\Leftrightarrow~~\text{ith term}=17\tag{2}$$

Moreover, I wrote the following.

Of course as we enumurate$~1,3,5,7,\cdot\cdot\cdot~$,9th term of this sequence takes 17.

We nextly focus on mth appearance of 17 of$~\left\{a\right\}~$

$$17_{m}:=\text{17 with mth appearnce}~~~\left(m\in\mathbb{N}\right)\tag{3}$$

$~m+8~$th groups'$~9~$th term$~~~\Leftrightarrow~~17_{m}~$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m+7}i=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(m+7\right)\left(1+\left(m+7\right)\right)\tag{4}$$

$$=\underbrace{\frac{\left(m+7\right)\left(m+8\right)}{2}}_{\text{number of terms of}~\left\{a\right\}~\text{till end of}~m+7~\text{th group}}\tag{5}$$

$$\therefore~~n=\frac{\left(m+7\right)\left(m+8\right)}{2}+9\tag{6}$$

Finished.